# How can I get the result with decimal number in division? C++, Pi

Tags: c++, double, decimal, division, pi

My school give me an assignment to calculate pi.

The result should be :

```
Question 4
Accuracy set at : 1000

term               pi
1                  4
100                3.13159
200                3.13659
300                3.13826
400                ...
...                ...
```

The result in my program :

```
term               pi
1                  4
100                3
200                3
300                3
400                ...
...                ...
```

I guess that when I do (4 / denominator), the result will lose the decimal number although I have changed some declarations of data type from int to double.
(Some websites tell me to do this.) 
Maybe I do it wrongly.

How can I deal with this problem?

The following is my program.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class Four
{
private:
    int inputedAccuracy;
    double pi;
    int denominator;
    int doneTermCounter;
    double oneTerm;
    int negativeController;

public:
    double question4()
    {
        cout << "Accuracy set at : " ;
        cin >> inputedAccuracy;
        cout << endl;
        pi = 0.0;
        denominator = 1.0;
        doneTermCounter = 0;

        negativeController = 1;
        cout << "Term" << "            " << "pi" << endl;
        cout << "1  " << "             " << "4" << endl;


        for (inputedAccuracy; inputedAccuracy > 0; inputedAccuracy -= 100)
        {
            for (int doneTerm = 0; doneTerm < 100; doneTerm++)
            {
                pi = pi + (negativeController * 4 / denominator);
                negativeController *= -1;
                denominator += 2;
                doneTermCounter++;
            }
            if (doneTermCounter >= 10000)
                cout << doneTermCounter << "             " << pi << endl;
            else
                if (doneTermCounter >= 1000)
                    cout << doneTermCounter << "            " << pi << endl;
                else
                    cout << doneTermCounter << "             " << pi << endl;
        }
        return 0.0;
    }
};
```

**Thank you for your attention!**

Comment: The least intrusive fix is: Change the 4 in 'pi = pi + (negativeController * 4 / denominator);' to 4.0

Comment: You mean pi isn't equal to 3??? What about the Bible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
pi = pi + (negativeController * 4 / denominator);
```

The `(negativeController * 4 / denominator)` expression results in an `int` because both `negativeController` and `denominator` are `int`. In other words, you're doing an integer division here which explains why you don't get the expected result.

Declare either (or both) of them as `double` to force a floating-point division.

Comment: The problem have been solved.
Thank you for your attention. XD

Answer (score 2):

```
pi = pi + (negativeController * 4 / denominator);
```

In this line, you have an integer division (because both operands of `/` are of type `int`), meaning that the fractional part of the division's result is discarded.

To use floating point division, at least one operand/side needs to be of type `float` or `(long) double`. The easiest way to achieve this would in this case be a change of `4` (a literal of type `int`) to `4.0` (a literal of type `double`):

Then, when calculating the result of `*`, `negativeController` will also be converted to `double` (*usual arithmetic conversions*), yielding a `double` as the left-hand side operand of `/` which in turn causes `denominator` (the rhs) to also be converted into a `double` and so on.

Comment: The problem have been solved. Thank you for your attention. XD

Answer (score 2):

You should change :-

`int denominator;` to

`double denominator;`

See [**here**](http://ideone.com/6GNVw2)

Comment: The problem have been solved. Thank you for your attention. XD

Answer (score 1):

I think changing `negativeController` and `denominator` to `int` would do the trick as the sub-expression is being evaluated on integers thus loosing precision.

Comment: The problem have been solved. Thank you for your attention. XD

Comment: @KinLi I thought I would be rewarded with an upvote.

Comment: I really want to give you a voteup but "Vote Up requires 15 reputation."