# Addition Operator Overloading in C++

Tags: c++, class, oop

This is a Rational Number class I am working on...
and following is one of the object constructors.

`using namespace std;`

```
RationalNumber::RationalNumber (const double &x){
    double temp = abs(x);

    int numerator = temp;
    int denominator = 1;
    double fraction = temp - numerator;

    while (fraction > 0) {
        temp *= 10; // Moves the decimal to the right
        numerator = temp; // Updates the Rational Number
        denominator *= 10;
        fraction = temp - numerator; // Updates the fraction
    }
    if (x < 0)
        numerator = -numerator;

    this->a = numerator; // Assigns the Calculated value
    this->b = denominator;

    standardize(); // Changes the values of the object to change it to standard form
    reduce(); // Changes the Rational Number to irreducible fraction
    count++; // Update Count objects
}
```

I am trying to add 2 Rational Numbers, by using the following operator overloading.

```
RationalNumber RationalNumber::operator+(const RationalNumber &r) const {
   RationalNumber A;
   int a1 = this->a;
   int b1 = this->b;
   int a2 = r.a;
   int b2 = r.b;
            // a1/b1 + a2/b2    = > a1*b2 + a2*b1 / b1*b2;
   A.a = a1*b2 + a2*b1;
   A.b = b1*b2;
   return A;
}
RationalNumber RationalNumber::operator+(const int& integer) const {
   RationalNumber A;
   A.a = integer;
   A.b = 1;
   return *this + A;
}
RationalNumber RationalNumber::operator+(const double& decimal) const {
   RationalNumber A(decimal);
   return *this + A;
}
RationalNumber RationalNumber::operator+(const float& decimal) const {
   RationalNumber A(static_cast<double>(decimal));
   return *this + A;
}
```

But, I am not getting the desired output from this function. The following is the debug window.

```
::::::::::::  Arithmetic Operators  :::::::::::::::
-----------------------------------------------------
(1/2)   +   (1/2)   =   (1/1)
(1/2)   +   3   =   (7/2)
3   +   (1/2)   =   (7/2)
(1/2)   +   0   =   (1/2)
3   +   (1/2)   =   (1/2)
(1/2)   +   4   =   (9/2)
3   +   (1/2)   =   (9/2)
-----------------------------------------------------
```

Below is the function I made to get this output.

```
void math_plus() {  
        RationalNumber a1 (1,2);
    RationalNumber sum = (a1 + a1);
    cout << a1 << "\t+\t" << a1 << "\t=\t" << sum << endl;

    int random = rand() % 10;
    sum = (a1 + random);
    cout << a1 << "\t+\t" << random << "\t=\t" <<  sum << endl;
    cout << random << "\t+\t" << a1 << "\t=\t" <<  sum << endl;

    double random2 = (rand() % 101) / 10;
    sum = (a1 + random2);
    cout << a1 << "\t+\t"<< random2 << "\t=\t" << sum << endl;
    cout << random << "\t+\t" << a1 << "\t=\t" <<  sum << endl;

    float random3 = (rand() % 101) / 10;
    sum = (a1 + random3);
    cout << a1 << "\t+\t" << random3 << "\t=\t" << sum << endl;
    cout << random << "\t+\t" << a1 << "\t=\t" <<  sum << endl;
}
```

I suspect that there is some error with the function call? as `random2` and `random3` should be decimal points, but they aren't.

Comment: Link for the whole Cpp file - https://github.com/singhmeharjeet/Rational-Number/blob/main/main.cpp

Comment: What output do you expect? And why are you printing things as if you expect `random` and `random2` to be equal?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19077585/

Comment: aschepler, Thanks man, I can't believe I overlooked that.